# Serve Angular App and its API using Express

Tags: angular, express, mod-rewrite, apache2, reverse-proxy

I have an Express app set up with has this routing configuration:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../angular-app/dist')));
app.use('/', 
  express.Router().get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('index.html');
  })
);
app.use('/v1', v1); // these are my API routes
```

If I launch this express app and navigate (in a browser) to its root, the Angular app comes up, but if I navigate to any of the routes *within* the Angular app, e.g. /mycomponent/ I get the 404 route rendering from Express.

What I want to have happen is that any route that doesn't start with /v1 is delegated to the angular app, and otherwise my API is served. Is this not a sound way of thinking about how to deploy this pair of applications?

To compound this, I have this hosted on an Apache server using a reverse proxy configuration.

```
   <Location /myapp>
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
      ProxyPassReverse http://1127.0.0.1:3000
   </Location>
```

... and of course my angular app has `<base href="/myapp/"/>` in its index.html template to support this. So I'm wondering if the only way to do this "correctly" is to use the reverse proxy for the Express app and have it *only* serve the API routes, then use some kind of mod_rewrite configuration in Apache to host the Angular app directly from Apache. What do you think?

Comment: try `app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../angular-app/dist/index.html'));
});`

Comment: @ChauTran yes, that was super easy thanks! Turn it into an answer and I'll accept it. I literally copy-pasted your suggestion after the `app.use('/v1;, v1) line above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../angular-app/dist/index.html'));
});
```

Put the above code block before your `routes` middlewares.

The reason is Angular is a SPA which means it has to load the `index.html` with all the corresponding `*.js` and in one of those `*.js`, there's your `RouterModule` with your defined `Routes`. At the point you navigate to another route by typing in the  `domain/route`, or refresh on `domain/route` which is not the `root`, `index.html` hasn't been loaded yet. Thus, the browser is not aware of your `Routes` definition from Angular.